# EJS - include with parentheses is not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am using EJS js and the include not working as excepted. i would like for help please :)

The versions that i am using are:

- ejs: ^3.1.3
- ejs-locals: ^1.0.2
- express: ^4.17.1

The problem:
Whenever I am using include, It does not work with parentheses, and I have to use it with a problematic way - for example:

```
<%- include ../components/card.ejs %>
```

But this way i can not do 2 things that I have to do:

1. use dynamic include (the file name as a variable) - for example:

   ```
    <%- include('../components/' + variable) %>
   ```
2. send a variable with the include - for example:

   ```
    <%- include('../components/card.ejs', {user: variable}) %>
   ```

The ways that I have used here are from the EJS documentation, so it should work...

errors:

- Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yosisms/Documents/Projects/Raven/views/pages/home/user/show', {user: user});.ejs'
- Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/yosisms/Documents/Projects/Raven/views/pages/home/user/show');.ejs'

please please help me :)
Thanks!

EDIT:
found the problem!!!
the problem was using the package ejs-locals.

Comment: Did you read the errors?

Comment: Can you show the actual code you're using? Given that the error does not fit the lines you posted? (aside: ejs is garbage, use pug instead) Also, these error messages suggest you've gotten the syntax wrong, i.e. you've put the additional params inside the quotes

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems to me like you just copy-pasted from the documentation. Are you sure that you have a `user` variable? The error references `{ user: user }` but your question mentions `{ user: variable }` instead.

Comment: lol it was an example, i am using my variables ofc...

Comment: an example of is:
`<% for (let i = 0; i < components.length; i++) { %>
    <%- include('../../components/' + components[i].componentType, {component: components[i]}); -%>`

<% } %>